# AndroidStudio dont shows devices from Genymotion

Tags: android-studio, genymotion

[Genymotion ADB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzAWj.png) I downloaded Genymotion, because the standard Android studio emulator is very slow. I downloaded the plugin for AS, changed the ADB in the Genymotion settings as it was said on the Internet. The first time, right after installing the plugin, I was able to launch the module in AS using a device from geny. But after closing both applications and trying to restart, AS does not offer a device from geny, although the plugin says that the device is turned on. I tried all of the found options: put the launch on behalf of the administrator, started the AS first then the geny and vice versa, but the devices did not appear again.